# Show UIScrollVIew on top of UITableViewController using storyboards

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

When I press a `Tab Bar Button` I want to show a `UIScrollView` on the entire iPhone screen on top of a `UITableView`.

I managed to do this programatically using this code:

```
-(IBAction)displayMenu
{
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                0,
                                                                [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                                                                [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height + 50)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    scrollView.alpha = 0.5;

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

But I want to add some other controls inside the `UIScrollView` so it's easier for me to do this using storyboards. But I don't know exactly where to put the `UIScrollView` when I drag it on the table view controller so it can be hidden until I press the button.

This is how my Scene looks for the `UITableViewController`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal `UIViewController` instead of the `UITableViewController` and add your `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` in it's view. Then just hide/show the scroll view.